# Additional margin of 5px when inline-table or inline block is used

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/xarq5/

```
 <div id="hello">
      <ul>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>Hello</li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

And css for the above html

```
  #hello{
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     border:1px solid black;
     float:left;
  }
  #hello ul{
      position:relative;
      display: inline-block;
      list-style:none;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
  } 
  #hello li{
       float:left;
  }
```

For the above html and css,  I always get a additional 5px margin for the ul element.

After meticulously going though each css statements line by line from my code and writing the above example, I was able to find that the problem was due to

```
    display:inline-block;
    or
    display:inline-table;
```

What is proper way to over come this?

some other forums suggest to use

"Set font-size: 0; for parent container and font-size: your_size; for children."

Is there any other solution to prevent this so that my font size of 0 doesn't cascade down to children.

Thank you
Srikanth

Comment: none of the answers worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try http://jsfiddle.net/xarq5/10/

```
#hello{
    float: left;
}
```

and

```
#hello ul {
    float: left
}
```

**explanation:** whenever you have an html element that's containing other floating elements, the containing element doesn't fully "contain" the floating elements unless if it's floated itself..

**note:** unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15230353/766570) answer you can keep your html indented as it was (ie don't worry about spacing or the lack thereof):

```
<body>   
    <div id="hello">
        <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding `vertical-align: middle;` to `#hello ul` will get rid of the undesirable "padding" at the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/xarq5/1/

The default vertical-alignment is usually `baseline`, which refers to the bottom edge of letters that don't have descenders ("a" or "B" do not have descenders, but "y" or "g" do).  The fiddle below makes it a little more obvious where the undesirable "padding" is coming from.  It isn't padding at all, but space reserved for the text's descenders.

http://jsfiddle.net/xarq5/11/

```
p {
    border: 1px solid;
}

p.aligned img {
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

<p>Something texty <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></p>

<p class="aligned">Something texty <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></p>
```

---

If the problem is undesirable spacing that happens *between* inline-block/inline-table elements and you don't want your source to look like a giant run-on sentence, then you can use comments.

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li><!--
    --><li>b</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I may not be well versed with vertical alignment Can I get a explanation on why we need to do this ?

Comment: I've added a brief explanation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also set the `li` to have no margin or padding if you don't want any space. Try to set it to `inline` only.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set `display: block;` to `ul` element set `display: inline-block;` to `li` element.